# CSS left pixel change by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Right arrow is not moving the car, I apologize if its something obvious but I couldn't figure out why.

**http://jsfiddle.net/W9HDt/**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $(document).keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 39) {
                    $(".car").css("left", "+=25px");
                }
            });

 });
```

according to [Javascript Char Codes (Key Codes)](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)  `39` is the code for the right arrow key

Comment: that is odd, when I tried your code it was the apostrophe that moved the car, but when I tried Arun's code it was the right arrow that moved the car.  must be different sets of code that are run at the different time,  that is the only explanation that I can think of for why they would be different at different points in time

Comment: @Malachi try "keyup" instead of "keypress" function

Comment: I did that. I am just saying that the Key at Value `39` changes to the apostrophe if you use `.keypress` rather then `keydown` or `keyup` I think **Arun** explained it that there is a different set of values for `keypress`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key press event may not be fired for [non-display keys](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2606) like arrow keys, try `keydown` or `keyup` instead.

[Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20100907/#events-keyboard-event-order) : keypress (only for keys which produce a character value)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 39) {
            $(".car").css("left", "+=25px");
        }
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XMsQw/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W9HDt/10/)

**`e.which` value for 3 is 51 not 39.**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $(document).keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 51) {
                    $(".car").css("left", "+=25px");
                }
            });


 });
```

[Check the Reference](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)

Comment: Which browser and os are you using

Comment: if you type in 3 the car moves.

Comment: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes where did you get 51 ? the table says otherwise.

Comment: @Malachi that is what am saying if we type 3 the car will move because  3 of e.which value is 51

Comment: @codingfreak add that link to your question as a reference link please, it will help people give better answers, even though there is already an accepted answer

Comment: in chrome on windows 7,  but the OP wants to use the `right arrow` key, not the `3` key

Comment: @Malachi oh i see i thought 3 is the correct answer.so OP want to move the car when 3 is typed. Thanks for Info Cheers

Comment: @codingfreak sorry i might understood wrongly.the reason why page itself moving is there is scroller that is why.So key up correct solution at this case

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been answered and the answer has been accepted but I don't think it is the best possible answer.

It is not true that the keypress event only triggers with visible character values. It does trigger with any key press but the problem is you are checking against the wrong event property, which instead of keyCode. Otherwise try this:

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        $(".car").css("left", "+=25px");
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        $(".car").css("left", "-=25px");
    }
});
```

The keyup and keydown events only trigger when the key is respectively released or pressed down. If you want to hold the key down and see the car moving the way to go is to use keyCode.

Have fun driving around!

And the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/JyJTb/)